# CSS grid doesn't work in Chrome but works in other browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, grid, gallery

It works in Firefox, Edge and Safari but not Chrome.

https://giovanniroverso.com/p_gal.php, for example, has a grid gallery near the bottom of the page which does not display in Chrome and I can't figure out why.

Help, please?

Thanks

Comment: It works on one browser but not the other, sounds like it's compatibility reason. But really? I opened the page you mentioned on both Firefox and Chrome and didn't see anything that appeared on Firefox but transparent on Chrome, could you please bring a capture of the difference you mentioned above?

Comment: The problem is the percentage heights you've set on the img elements (`max-height: 100%`). You haven't declared a parent reference, so the elements are collapsing. See the duplicates for more details.

Comment: it was working on chrome as well.

Comment: Thanks Michael_B, that is the problem.

thing is I define the .item divs in the grid statement to be 250px

Comment: `.container-gallery {
grid-area: container-gallery;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 2em;
    align-items: center;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: 2em;
}`

Comment: OK! I changed max-height: 100%; to height-100%. THAT SOLVES IT! WOW this has been traumatizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed max-height: 100%; to height-100%. THAT SOLVES IT!

Thanks again Micahel_B!